Why is the plot of the refractive index wavelength-dependent Fresnel's equation not showing as expected?
I want to reproduce the reflectance spectrum of a thin film whose complex refractive index is wavelength-dependent (the complex refractive index data, named N2 in code, can be obtained from here).
Using fresnel's equations  for medium 1: air, medium 2: thin film, and medium 3: air :
  ; 
The reflection coefficient   
where \delta is defined as 
And finally the reflectance equation 
Since the refractive indices have a dependence on the wavelength, then the refraction angle   have the same dependence, using the Snell equation: 
I wrote the following code:
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

## Function definition
def Ang_Refrac(na,nb,angle_a):
ang_refrac = np.arcsin( (na/nb).real * np.sin(angle_a) )
return ang_refrac

# Data
Thin_film = pd.read_csv("Si_refractive index.txt", delimiter='\t')

## Variable definition

# thin film thickness, [d]: nm
d = 200

# Wave-length
lamb = Thin_film[Thin_film.columns[0]]

# Complex refractive index
N1 = np.ones(len(lamb))
N2 = Thin_film[Thin_film.columns[1]] + Thin_film[Thin_film.columns[1]]*1j
N3 = np.ones(len(lamb))

# Angle:
ang_1_s = 0  #sexagesimal

ang_1 = ang_1_s*np.pi/180  #radians
ang_2 = [] #radians
ang_3 = [] #radians
for i in range(len(N2)):
    ang_refrac_12 = Ang_Refrac(N1[i],N2[i],ang_1)
    ang_refrac_23 = Ang_Refrac(N2[i],N3[i],ang_refrac_12)
    ang_2.append(ang_refrac_12)
    ang_3.append(ang_refrac_23)

## Reflectance
R_s = np.zeros(len(lamb))
R_p = np.zeros(len(lamb))

for i in range(len(lamb)):
    # S-type polarization
    r12_s = (N1[i]*np.cos(ang_1) - N2[i]*np.cos(ang_2[i]))/(N1[i]*np.cos(ang_1) + N2[i]*np.cos(ang_2[i]))
    r23_s = (N2[i]*np.cos(ang_2[i]) - N3[i]*np.cos(ang_3[i]))/(N2[i]*np.cos(ang_2[i]) + N3[i]*np.cos(ang_3[i]))

    # P-type polarization
    r12_p = (N2[i]*np.cos(ang_1) - N1[i]*np.cos(ang_2[i])) / (N2[i]*np.cos(ang_1) + N1[i]*np.cos(ang_2[i]))
    r23_p = (N3[i]*np.cos(ang_2[i]) - N2[i]*np.cos(ang_3[i])) / (N3[i]*np.cos(ang_2[i]) + N2[i]*np.cos(ang_3[i]))

    # Phase shift
    delta = 2 * np.pi * (1/lamb[i]) * d * np.sqrt(abs(N2[i])**2 - (np.sin(ang_1)**2))

    # Reflection coefficient
    r123_s = (r12_s + r23_s*np.exp(2j*delta)) / (1 - r12_s*r23_s*np.exp(2j*delta))
    r123_p = (r12_p + r23_p*np.exp(2j*delta)) / (1 - r12_p*r23_p*np.exp(2j*delta))

    # Reflectance
    R_s[i] = abs(r123_s)**2
    R_p[i] = abs(r123_p)**2


# Reflectance normalization
R_s_normalized = (R_s - min(R_s)) / (max(R_s) - min(R_s))
R_p_normalized = (R_p - min(R_p)) / (max(R_p) - min(R_p))

# Plotting
plt.title("Refletância $\phi=" + str(ang_1_s) + "$°")
plt.xlim(300, 1000)  # Definindo os limites do eixo x
plt.plot(lamb, R_s_normalized, 'go', label="Polarização S", markersize=4)
plt.plot(lamb, R_p_normalized, 'b-', label="Polarização P")
plt.legend()
plt.show()

Resulting graph:

Expected graph: Obtained from here

Why are the results not the same?

Hi! From the code you posted, it looks like you have the data in a txt file on Google Drive. Could you edit the post to include a public link to said file? I know you have included a link to the original data source but 1) it is not completely clear to me what I should download 2) using the same data as yours will make it possible to reproduce your result. Furthermore, I think it could be useful to add a reference to Fresnel's law (even a link to Wikipedia) to show where to get the formulas from.

Hi @Pxndx! Thanks for updating your question! Unfortunately, the reference to data you posted is not formatted as your code expects, resulting in an IndexError after few lines. Could you please provide the exact data file you're using, formatted correctly for replication? Additionally, including the equations is a good start. Still, a reference to the theory behind the equations would greatly help understand the variables and ensure the calculations' correctness.

Thank-you for updating your question, @Pxndx. Are you sure that, in the expression for N2, + Thin_film[Thin_film.columns[1]]*1j shouldn't be + Thin_film[Thin_film.columns[2]]*1j (as I expect the complex refractive index to be n+ik. Secondly, please explain where the expression for delta comes from (especially if N2 is complex).

You can try this. The major changes are:

N2 is given by n + i.k, rather than n + i.n as you had

there is just N2 ** 2 in the expression for delta, not abs(N2)**2, which would lose an important complex part

I think the reflection coefficients should have a '+', not a '-' sign in the denominator (though I could be wrong).


I found a little bit of background (and a few typos) in https://ir.lib.nycu.edu.tw/bitstream/11536/27329/1/000186822000019.pdf
Code:
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

## Function definition
def Ang_Refrac(na,nb,angle_a):
    ang_refrac = np.arcsin( (na/nb) * np.sin(angle_a) )
    return ang_refrac

# Data
Thin_film = pd.read_csv("Si_refractive index.txt", delimiter='\t')

d = 200                                         # thin film thickness, [d]: nm
lamb = Thin_film[Thin_film.columns[0]]          # Wave-length

# Complex refractive index       n + ik
num = len(lamb)
N1 = np.ones(num)
N2 = Thin_film[Thin_film.columns[1]] + Thin_film[Thin_film.columns[2]]*1j      # <=========== NOTE ======
N3 = np.ones(num)

# Angle:
ang_1_s = 0
ang_1 = ang_1_s * np.pi / 180
ang_2 = [] #radians
ang_3 = [] #radians
for i in range(num):
    ang_refrac_12 = Ang_Refrac(N1[i],N2[i],ang_1)
    ang_refrac_23 = Ang_Refrac(N2[i],N3[i],ang_refrac_12)
    ang_2.append(ang_refrac_12)
    ang_3.append(ang_refrac_23)

## Reflectance
R_s = np.zeros(num)
R_p = np.zeros(num)

for i in range(num):
    # S-type polarization
    r12_s = (N1[i]*np.cos(ang_1) - N2[i]*np.cos(ang_2[i]))/(N1[i]*np.cos(ang_1) + N2[i]*np.cos(ang_2[i]))
    r23_s = (N2[i]*np.cos(ang_2[i]) - N3[i]*np.cos(ang_3[i]))/(N2[i]*np.cos(ang_2[i]) + N3[i]*np.cos(ang_3[i]))

    # P-type polarization
    r12_p = (N2[i]*np.cos(ang_1) - N1[i]*np.cos(ang_2[i])) / (N2[i]*np.cos(ang_1) + N1[i]*np.cos(ang_2[i]))
    r23_p = (N3[i]*np.cos(ang_2[i]) - N2[i]*np.cos(ang_3[i])) / (N3[i]*np.cos(ang_2[i]) + N2[i]*np.cos(ang_3[i]))

    # Phase shift
    delta = 2 * np.pi * ( d / lamb[i] ) * np.sqrt( N2[i]**2 - np.sin(ang_1)**2)       # <====== NOTE ====

    # Reflection coefficient
    r123_s = (r12_s + r23_s*np.exp(2j*delta)) / (1 + r12_s*r23_s*np.exp(2j*delta))    # <====== NOTE ====
    r123_p = (r12_p + r23_p*np.exp(2j*delta)) / (1 + r12_p*r23_p*np.exp(2j*delta))    # <====== NOTE ====

    # Reflectance
    R_s[i] = abs( r123_s ) ** 2
    R_p[i] = abs( r123_p ) ** 2


# Reflectance normalization
R_s_normalized = ( R_s - min( R_s ) ) / ( max( R_s ) - min( R_s ) )
R_p_normalized = ( R_p - min( R_p ) ) / ( max( R_p ) - min( R_p ) )

# Plotting
plt.title( r"Refletancia $\phi=" + str(ang_1_s) + "$ deg")
plt.xlim(300, 1000)  # Definindo os limites do eixo x
plt.plot(lamb, R_s_normalized, 'go', label="Polarizacao S", markersize=4)
plt.plot(lamb, R_p_normalized, 'b-', label="Polarizacao P")
plt.legend()
plt.show()

Output (note: some systematic difference in the normalisation from your "expected")


I assumed N2 must be real since it is inside the square root, and forgot that delta would multiply with i. Regarding the sign in the reflection coefficient, it is still not clear to me why some references use + and others -
Thanks for the help.
